# Windows 10 task manager, under Details tab->Commit size, clearly didn't add up to what have shown in Performance->Memory->Commited

Tags: windows-10, memory-management

I know what committed means, just don't understand where all it goes.

[Performance Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCcxd.png)

[Start of process list, sorted by commit size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSYNS.png)

[End of process list, sorted by commit size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9z2T.png)

Comment: Please be more clear, what is it that you didn’t understand.

Comment: @Valay_17, Performance Tab showed 28GiB committed. But process list->commit size column clearly didn't add up to 28GiB.

Comment: Did you consider some amount of Memory being used by Windows as well?

Comment: It's *possible* that you have a memory leak, with all the Chrome processes you've got running. You need to establish a baseline. Disable Fast Startup if it's enabled, then restart your PC after closing all the programs you have opened (wait a minute or two, to give them time to write to disk what they have to). Once your PC has restarted, don't open any program other than those set to start at boot, and check your Task Manager for RAM usage. You should see some improvement. Then open Chrome, and see what happens then.

Comment: @Didier amount of leaked memory should be included in commit size.

Comment: Maybe it is. It's hard to tell with all those processes. Plus, memory usage is dynamic, especially when it comes to web browsers, where page content can be refreshed, thus triggering a surge in RAM usage. Did you try to do what I suggested? Did you notice an improvement?

Comment: @Didier After closing Chrome with no chrome.exe in process list, there's still a 24GiB(committed)/4GB(in active use) ratio.

Comment: OK, but did you try to restart your PC too?

Answer (score 1):

[Download](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) Process Explorer from Microsoft, then enable all columns.

And I found a process called runSW.exe is showing **22GiB Shared Commit**, after a simple Google a similar [report](https://what.thedailywtf.com/topic/17472/finally-nailed-my-windows-memory-leak-a-k-a-the-official-we-hate-karl-club/7) came up.

After killing the process and disable RunSwUSB service, all things go well.

Now the problem solved, but still not satisfied with it hide so well under Shared Commit, and no good document is describing which syscall in programming(preferably in C) will lead into this hidden trouble, hope someone will complete this answer by adding that detail.

Comment: I'm glad you've pinpointed the origin of your extreme RAM usage. For the rest, this process comes installed with Realtek drivers, apparently when you use a network dongle such as an Ethernet-over-USB adapter. If that's the case, then you may have to face this issue again, because it's known for its tendency to gobble up RAM and CPU cycles. If not, you can simply delete the RunSWUSB folder in your Windows folder.